# Definable curves in definable sets

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, model-theory

Suppose that I have an unbounded subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, definable in the $o$-minimal structure $\mathbb{R}_{an, exp}$. Is it possible to find an unbounded, analytic and definable curve (i.e. real-analytic set of dimension one) contained in $X$?

Comment: Can you clarify some of the notation?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: $\mathbb R_\mathrm{an}$ is the expansion of the real field $(\mathbb R,+,\cdot)$ by all functions $[0,1]^n\to\mathbb R$ that are real-analytic in a neighbourhood of $[0,1]^n$. $\mathbb R_{\mathrm{an},\exp}$ is the same thing further expanded with the exponential $\exp\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Is there more notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you can find  an unbounded  definable curve $C\subset X$.   Any  set in $\mathbb{R}_{an, exp}$ admits a *finite* stratification by real analytic submanifolds.  Pick one such stratification of $C$. One of the strata of this stratification is an unbounded  real analytic curve contained in $C$ and, a fortiori, in $X$.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it is really helpful. Can you please if possible give a reference for the existence of this analytic stratification; I apologise - I am really not familiar with this theory....also does the same thing hold in the structure R_{an} (generated by the restricted analytic functions)? Note that unboundedness is essential to me... Many thanks again!

Comment: Check Sec. 8 of the paper *ON THE  REAL  EXPONENTIAL  FIELD WITH  RESTRICTED  ANALYTIC  FUNCTIONS* by C. Miller and L. Van der Dries, Israle. J. Math. vol.85(1994), 19-56.

Answer (score 1):

This holds in any o-minimal structure. First perform an inversion $i\colon x\mapsto x/\|x\|^2$ so that the origin becomes a limit point of $i(X)$. Then apply the *Curve selection lemma*: for every definable set $A$ in an o-minimal structure,  and any limit point $a\in \overline A$, there exists a definable map $f\colon \mathopen]0;1]\to A$ such that that $\lim_0 f=a$. Then perform the inversion again: the image of the map $i\circ f$ is an unbounded definable curve in $X$.

Comment: What happened to “analytic”?

Comment: Very nice answer! I assume the "analytic" condition goes into the definition of the appropriate o-minimal structure?

Comment: @Emil I overlooked this requirement, which won't necessary hold in general (take for $X$ a nowhere analytic o-minimal curve) but can be recovered in $R_{\rm an,exp}$.

Comment: Would it (analytic condition) hold in R_{an}? I believe yes....

Comment: Yes. In $\mathbf R_{\rm an,exp}$, every definable function from an interval of $\mathbf R$ to $\mathbf R$ is piecewise analytic (on open intervals).